# What does "You are the creator and an author for this paper. You have authored an accepted paper." mean in EDAS?

Tags: publications, conference, paper-submission

What does "You are the creator and an author for this paper. You have authored an accepted paper." mean in EDAS when the Status is still "Active (has manuscript)"?

Comment: Have you asked the journal production team? What do they say?

Answer (score 1):

If you have sent multiple manuscripts to the same conference, this means you have at least one of them been accepted.